# Android - how to disable long press on Search button (Nexus One)

Tags: android, search

The Android documentation describes how to disable the search the search feature in Activity:
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    return false;
 }

This works fine for a short press of the search button on the Nexus One.
However, it doesn't disable the long press, which still fires off a voice search.

How do I disable the long press Voice search?

Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

I extended Stan's answer to only disable long press events.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH
        && (event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) == KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: @Styler, often `(flags & mask)` alone is sufficient to satisfy an `&&` -- why is `(flags & mask) == mask` necessary in your most recent (still pending) edit? Is `FLAG_LONG_PRESS` a multi-bit mask, of which one or more underlying bits might be turned on?

Comment: @sarnold it didn't compile for me until I actually did this `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH && (event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) == KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS)`

Comment: My understanding is that it's necessary in Java because `flags & MASK` is an int/long and `&&` requires a bool. However, it's probably better to use `(flags & FLAG_FOO) != 0` which is more resilient to typos (how long would it take you to notice `(flags & FLAG_FOO) == FLAG_BAR` is always false?).

Comment: @Styler, excellent, thanks. :) I've had my head in C-land long enough that I had long forgotten that `&&` requires a `bool`.

Comment: I don't know, but when i click the editText and reclick the same edittext, i am still getting the the option for cut copy paste. :-(

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like a very nice thing to do to users, but onKeyDown can be used to disable both tap and long press search in an Activity as shown here:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android 2.0, you can do that :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
        // todo your code here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```