# Creating Menu's based on touch events (Android/Opengl1.0)

Tags: android, opengl-es, menu

I have a Activity class and a Renderer class (extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer).
Inside the Renderer class, I have  an "onTouchEvent" method to handle touch events like rotation.

Now, I want to display a Menu that pops up on touching some part of the screen. I found that I need to implement a Menu in the Activity class(as we get the MenuInflator object here). However, I want to implement the Menu inside the onTouchEvent in my Renderer class so that the Menu shows up when some part of the screen is touched.

How can I implement this?

I am using Android/java/opengl1.0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can do what you want with a context menu, which integrates well.
You can either override `onCreateContextMenu()` in the activity and disable long press for context menu etc. or implement this method with another name.
Then, you have to call this method from inside your renderer, which has access to its enclosing activity. Maybe, you want to move some invariant params like `View v` into the method.

```
public void createMyContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

[Android - how to disable long press on Search button (Nexus One)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215004/1175253)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it as a context menu. You can bring this up at any time (e.g. in response to a custom onTouchEvent as you asked) by calling [View.showContextMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#showContextMenu%28%29). The context menu has to be defined inside the containing Activity, but it is possible to set up a protocol between the View and Activity to add View-specific behaviour. If you look at the code for the SlideView class in my [Infinirule](https://github.com/ldo/infinirule_android) app, you will see how I bring up different context menus depending on which part of the display is touched.