# Android - How to fix Widget size always 4x2

Tags: android

I am making a widget application with size 4x2.
When long pressing on my widget, the user can change size to 4x3 or 4x1, 4x4. It makes some strings on my widget display badly. I do not want the user to be able to change my widget size, It should be always 4x2.
How can I fix the widget size?

My widget info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="146dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget1"
>
```

Comment: Setting the minHeight value to 40dp solved the problem.

Comment: @Sreekanthss I did it, but my widget so small. How to disable long press on my widget ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3836956

Answer (score 2):

May be a late answer, but setting the resize mode to "none" should solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="146p"
android:resizeMode="none"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget1"
>
```

Comment: This actually helped me, felt like a noob when I didn't see that xml attribute at first, thanks!